# How to bind two xml in one class in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I'm new to Kotlin. I have a `MainActivity` and a list view inside.

When an item is clicked in the list view, I want to update a textView inside `MainActivity`.

However because data should be passed from ListView to `MainActivity`, I did something weird:

`MainActivity.kt`:

```kotlin
data class Country(val imgRes:Int, val name:String)

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding
    private val data = arrayListOf<Country>()

    val imgRes = intArrayOf()

    val data1 = arrayOf()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        for(i in imgRes.indices) {
            val country = Country(imgRes[i], data1[i])
            data.add(country)
        }

        val adapter = RecyclerAdapter(data, object:RecyclerAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemClick(v: View, pos: Int) {
                binding.textView.text = (v as TextView).text
            }
        })
        binding.recycler1.adapter = adapter
        binding.recycler1.layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
    }
}
```

`ListView.kt`:

```
class RecyclerAdapter(private val dataSet:List<Country>, private val listener:OnItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(v:View, pos:Int)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding = RowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataSet.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(position)
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(val binding: RowBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        val rowImageView = binding.rowImageView
        val rowTextView = binding.rowTextView

        init {
            binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                listener.onItemClick(rowTextView, adapterPosition)
            }
        }

        fun bind(pos: Int) {
            with(binding) {
                rowImageView.setImageResource(dataSet[pos].imgRes)
                rowTextView.text = dataSet[pos].name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I declared interface(`OnItemClickListener`) at `ListView.kt` and redefine it at `MainActivity.kt`.
It works fine but is there any better way to do this?

Comment: you did allright dude.

Answer (score 1):

You can use higher order functions instead of interface.

Define this function top of your `Adapter`:

```
var onClick: ((text: String) -> Unit)? = null
```

in `ViewHolder`:

```
binding.root.setOnClickListener {
    onClick?.invoke(dataSet[position].text)
}
```

in `MainActivity`:

```
adapter.onClick = { name ->
    binding.textView.text = name
}
```

You can also find more information about higher orders in [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `Adapter`:

```
var itemClickListener: ((position: Int, name: String) -> Unit)? = null
```

`Bindviewholder`:

```
 itemClickListner.invoke(1,"anyvalue")
```

in `Activity`:

```
 adapter.itemClickListener = { 
            position, name ->
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"position is $position name is $name ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in `Adapter`:

```kotlin
    private var mListener: OnItemClickListener,

     interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onClick(position: Int, routerArray: ArrayList<Router>)
    }


     binding.yourView.setOnClickListener {
                mListener.onClick(adapterPosition, routerArray)
  }
```

in `Activity`:

```kotlin
      override fun onClick(position: Int, yourArray: ArrayList<Model>) {
         binding.textView.text = yourArray[position].text
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<include android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         layout="@layout/yourlayout" />
```